# How to run applet in spring roo

Tags: spring-roo

I'm very new to spring roo and I need help.

I have an applet that needs to be displayed to user.

Currently, without using spring roo, all .jar files are placed in the same folder as the html file. The applet is able to run.

In spring roo, I've tried to put the html and .jar files in a folder in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views. The page is accessible, but the .jar files isn't. The page displays a broken applet and it says that my Main class is not found.

I think adding resource files in views is not a proper way to write a webapp, but how do you do that properly in spring roo? I'm really clueless.

Answer (score 1):

Place your applet's jar outside `WEB-INF` folder. For example create `applets` folder in `{project_roo}/src/main/webapp` and pace your jar there (I mean `{project_roo}/src/main/webapp/applets`). You can refer it from the web as `http://{my_context_root}/applets/my-applet.jar`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It still can't work. I think this is the reason :

Caused by: java.io.IOException: open HTTP connection failed:http://localhost:8080/myapp/applet/org/someproject/applet/Main.class

Comment: So now applet is displaying to user but there are some other problems with applet itself?

Comment: Yes, the applet is able to load but failed to run. The applet's main class is "org.someproject.applet.Main". When I run it, spring somehow translate the address to localhost:8080/myapp/applet/org/someproject/applet/Main.class (you can see the similarities between main class path and this url path). And the path is not accessible with spring. So it failed to run.

I have tried to run the applet without spring and it ran very well.